# Continuous sending location to server.. good or bad?

Tags: android, httpconnection, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am developing one tracking application where a user can track other users location continuously and show it in map.For continuous location updates i am using  `FusedLocationApi` and getting location updates correctly. My question is to send these location to other device, is it a good habit to send these location updates to server continuously? If we make connection request to server so frequently then won't it be draining battery fast? Thanks in Advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I hope you need to ask this in any another place. You will get programming related questions and you are asking about implementation.

Comment: @Sree if you can go through my question once again, please do. I know i can send location to server using HttpsUrlConnection. what i am asking is- is it a good habit? or is there any other way? i am asking for an idea not an implementation.

Comment: I hope you know what is the limitation of implementing this and you also know what is the alternative for doing this. So what is the use of this question ?

Comment: @Sree yes i know the limitation, and where i have written that i know the alternative? I am asking for an idea.. If you dont know the answer its ok :) Don't spam it further.

Comment: As said this is not the place to get an idea, Sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not good actually because it consumes a lot part of battery and also network. But as per your requirement it is good. Even i am also working on almost same concept of application but it is okay coz there are no another solutions so keep moving on that...

Comment: yes right.. even i searched but didn't get any better way :|